# Homework help (Simulation Program)

Tags: java

I am taking an intro to java programming class however, I am having trouble with our third programming assignment. At first I thought I was on the right track because we just started to discuss loops this week (while loops) but I guess I'm just really struggling to wrap my mind around how I need to code this particular assignment. Now I have done alot of the work but I am just stuck on how to continue and of course my program was somewhat working now it's just a mess. Any help would be greatly appreciated. By the way I am not asking for this assignment to be done for me I just need help on how I can move forward because I am just very confused because I can't get my last while loop to continue after it's done iterating through the loop. Below is a summary of what I need to do along with my code:

An alien is reported to have landed on the moon. Luckily we have a spacecraft orbiting
the moon that can take pictures of the surface. During a 24 hour period the spacecraft can
orbit the moon 8 times. On each orbit the alien will be in range of the camera on our
spacecraft for 3 minutes. The camera can take 10 photos per minute. During the first
minute we estimate there is a 50% chance the alien will appear on each photo taken.
During the second minute we estimate there is a 75% chance the alien will appear on
each photo taken. During the third minute we estimate there is a 25% chance the alien
will appear on each photo taken.

Run a simulation of our spacecraft taking photos of the alien. For each picture taken, generate a random number from 0-100 and compare it to the percentage chance the alien
will appear in the photo. Calculate the number of photos taken during the 24 hour period
and output it to the screen. Calculate the number of photos taken during 24 hour period
in which the alien appears in the photo and output that to the screen also.

Run the above simulation 5 times. At the end, compute the average number of photos taken (rounded down) during a 24 hour period in which the alien appears (by averaging the number of photos taken of the alien during all of the 5 simulations)

```
public class Homework_3
```

{

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    //These are the declarations for most of my variables
    int count_of_sims = 0;
    int hours = 0;
    int minutes = 0;
    int photo_alien = 0;
    int count_of_photos = 0;
    /*int sum = 0;
    int avg = 0;*/
    double firstOrbit = 0.0;
    double secondOrbit = 0.0;
    double thirdOrbit = 0.0;
    double fourthOrbit = 0.0;
    double fifthOrbit = 0.0;
    double sixthOrbit = 0.0;
    double seventhOrbit = 0.0;
    double eigthOrbit = 0.0;

    //This while loop performs all five simulations
    while(count_of_sims < 6)
    {
        count_of_sims = count_of_sims + 1;

        //This while loop determines which orbit of the moon our spacecraft is on
        while(hours < 24)
        {
            hours = hours + 3;
            //This is the first orbit of the moon by our spacecraft
            if(hours == 3)
            {       
                //This while loop determines which minute we are on in regard to taking photos of the alien
                while(minutes < 4)
                {
                    minutes = minutes + 1;
                    //This is the first minute 
                    if(minutes == 1 && count_of_photos <=10)
                    {
                        firstOrbit = (int)(Math.random() *100) * .50;
                        photo_alien++;
                        count_of_photos++;
                        System.out.print("Simulation 1: Photos of alien: " + firstOrbit + " ,");
                    }
                    //This is the second minute
                    else if(minutes == 2 && count_of_photos <=10)
                    {
                        firstOrbit = (int)(Math.random() *100) * .75;
                        photo_alien++;
                        count_of_photos++;
                        System.out.print("Simulation 1: Photos of alien: " + firstOrbit + " ,");
                    }
                    //This is the third minute
                    else if(minutes == 3 && count_of_photos <=10)
                    {
                        firstOrbit = (int)(Math.random() *100) * .25;
                        photo_alien++;
                        count_of_photos++;
                        System.out.print("Simulation 1: Photos of alien: " + firstOrbit);
                    }
                    //break;
                    continue;
                }
            }
            //This is the second orbit of the moon by our spacecraft
            else if(hours == 6) 
            {
                //This while loop determines which minute we are on in regard to taking photos of the alien
                while(minutes < 4)
                {
                    minutes = minutes + 1;
                    //This is the first minute
                    if(minutes == 1 && count_of_photos <=10)
                    {
                        secondOrbit = (int)(Math.random() *100) * .50;
                        photo_alien++;
                        count_of_photos++;
                        System.out.println("Simulation 2: Photos of alien: " + secondOrbit + " ,");
                    }
                    //This is the second minute
                    else if(minutes == 2 && count_of_photos <=10)
                    {
                        secondOrbit = (int)(Math.random() *100) * .75;
                        photo_alien++;
                        count_of_photos++;
                        System.out.print("Simulation 2: Photos of alien: " + secondOrbit + " ,");
                    }
                    //This is the third minute
                    else if(minutes == 3 && count_of_photos <=10)
                    {
                        secondOrbit = (int)(Math.random() *100) * .25;
                        photo_alien++;
                        count_of_photos++;
                        System.out.print("Simulation 2: Photos of alien: " + secondOrbit);
                    }
                    //break;
                    continue;
                }
            }
            //This is the third orbit of the moon by our spacecraft
            else if(hours == 9) 
            {
                //This while loop determines which minute we are on in regard to taking photos of the alien
                while(minutes < 4)
                {
                    minutes = minutes + 1;
                    //This is the first minute
                    if(minutes == 1 && count_of_photos <=10)
                    {
                        thirdOrbit = (int)(Math.random() *100) * .50;
                        photo_alien++;
                        count_of_photos++;
                        System.out.println("Simulation 3: Photos of alien: " + thirdOrbit + " ,");
                    }
                    //This is the second minute
                    else if(minutes == 2 && count_of_photos <=10)
                    {
                        thirdOrbit = (int)(Math.random() *100) * .75;
                        photo_alien++;
                        count_of_photos++;
                        System.out.print("Simulation 3: Photos of alien: " + thirdOrbit + " ,");
                    }
                    //This is the third minute
                    else if(minutes == 3 && count_of_photos <=10)
                    {
                        thirdOrbit = (int)(Math.random() *100) * .25;
                        photo_alien++;
                        count_of_photos++;
                        System.out.print("Simulation 3: Photos of alien: " + thirdOrbit);
                    }
                    //break;
                    continue;
                }
            }
            //This is the fourth orbit of the moon by our spacecraft
            else if(hours == 12) 
            {
                //This while loop determines which minute we are on in regard to taking photos of the alien
                while(minutes < 4)
                {
                    minutes = minutes + 1;
                    //This is the first minute
                    if(minutes == 1 && count_of_photos <=10)
                    {
                        fourthOrbit = (int)(Math.random() *100) * .50;
                        photo_alien++;
                        count_of_photos++;
                        System.out.println("Simulation 4: Photos of alien: " + fourthOrbit + " ,");
                    }
                    //This is the second minute
                    else if(minutes == 2 && count_of_photos <=10)
                    {
                        fourthOrbit = (int)(Math.random() *100) * .75;
                        photo_alien++;
                        count_of_photos++;
                        System.out.print("Simulation 4: Photos of alien: " + fourthOrbit + " ,");
                    }
                    //This is the third minute
                    else if(minutes == 3 && count_of_photos <=10)
                    {
                        fourthOrbit = (int)(Math.random() *100) * .25;
                        photo_alien++;
                        count_of_photos++;
                        System.out.print("Simulation 4: Photos of alien: " + fourthOrbit + " ,");
                    }
                    //break;
                    continue;
                }
            }
            //This is the fifth orbit of the moon by our spacecraft
            else if(hours == 15) 
            {
                //This while loop determines which minute we are on in regard to taking photos of the alien
                while(minutes < 4)
                {
                    minutes = minutes + 1;
                    //This is the first minute
                    if(minutes == 1 && count_of_photos <=10)
                    {
                        fifthOrbit = (int)(Math.random() *100) * .50;
                        photo_alien++;
                        count_of_photos++;
                        System.out.println("Simulation 5: Photos of alien: " + fifthOrbit + " ,");
                    }
                    //This is the second minute
                    else if(minutes == 2 && count_of_photos <=10)
                    {
                        fifthOrbit = (int)(Math.random() *100) * .75;
                        photo_alien++;
                        count_of_photos++;
                        System.out.print("Simulation 5: Photos of alien: " + fifthOrbit + " ,");
                    }
                    //This is the third minute
                    else if(minutes == 3 && count_of_photos <=10)
                    {
                        fifthOrbit = (int)(Math.random() *100) * .25;
                        photo_alien++;
                        count_of_photos++;
                        System.out.print("Simulation 5: Photos of alien: " + fifthOrbit);
                    }
                    //break;
                    continue;
                }
            }
            //This is the sixth orbit of the moon by our spacecraft
            else if(hours == 18) 
            {
                //This while loop determines which minute we are on in regard to taking photos of the alien
                while(minutes < 4)
                {
                    minutes = minutes + 1;
                    //This is the first minute
                    if(minutes == 1 && count_of_photos <=10)
                    {
                        sixthOrbit = (int)(Math.random() *100) * .50;
                        photo_alien++;
                        count_of_photos++;
                        System.out.println("Simulation 6: Photos of alien: " + sixthOrbit + " ,");
                    }
                    //This is the second minute
                    else if(minutes == 2 && count_of_photos <=10)
                    {
                        sixthOrbit = (int)(Math.random() *100) * .75;
                        photo_alien++;
                        count_of_photos++;
                        System.out.print("Simulation 6: Photos of alien: " + sixthOrbit + " ,");
                    }
                    //This is the third minute
                    else if(minutes == 3 && count_of_photos <=10)
                    {
                        sixthOrbit = (int)(Math.random() *100) * .25;
                        photo_alien++;
                        count_of_photos++;
                        System.out.print("Simulation 6: Photos of alien: " + sixthOrbit);
                    }
                    //break;
                    continue;
                }
            }
            //This is the seventh orbit of the moon by our spacecraft
            else if(hours == 21) 
            {
                //This while loop determines which minute we are on in regard to taking photos of the alien
                while(minutes < 4)
                {
                    minutes = minutes + 1;
                    //This is the first minute
                    if(minutes == 1 && count_of_photos <=10)
                    {
                        seventhOrbit = (int)(Math.random() *100) * .50;
                        photo_alien++;
                        count_of_photos++;
                        System.out.println("Simulation 7: Photos of alien: " + seventhOrbit + " ,");
                    }
                    //This is the second minute
                    else if(minutes == 2 && count_of_photos <=10)
                    {
                        seventhOrbit = (int)(Math.random() *100) * .75;
                        photo_alien++;
                        count_of_photos++;
                        System.out.print("Simulation 7: Photos of alien: " + seventhOrbit + " ,");
                    }
                    //This is the third minute
                    else if(minutes == 3 && count_of_photos <=10)
                    {
                        seventhOrbit = (int)(Math.random() *100) * .25;
                        photo_alien++;
                        count_of_photos++;
                        System.out.print("Simulation 7: Photos of alien: " + seventhOrbit);
                    }
                    //break;
                    continue;
                }
            }
            //This is the eighth orbit of the moon by our spacecraft
            else if(hours == 24) 
            {
                //This while loop determines which minute we are on in regard to taking photos of the alien
                while(minutes < 4)
                {
                    minutes = minutes + 1;
                    //This is the first minute
                    if(minutes == 1 && count_of_photos <=10)
                    {
                        eigthOrbit = (int)(Math.random() *100) * .50;
                        photo_alien++;
                        count_of_photos++;
                        System.out.println("Simulation 8: Photos of alien: " + eigthOrbit + " ,");
                    }
                    //This is the second minute
                    else if(minutes == 2 && count_of_photos <=10)
                    {
                        eigthOrbit = (int)(Math.random() *100) * .75;
                        photo_alien++;
                        count_of_photos++;
                        System.out.print("Simulation 8: Photos of alien: " + eigthOrbit + " ,");
                    }
                    //This is the third minute
                    else if(minutes == 3 && count_of_photos <=10)
                    {
                        eigthOrbit = (int)(Math.random() *100) * .25;
                        photo_alien++;
                        count_of_photos++;
                        System.out.print("Simulation 8: Photos of alien: " + eigthOrbit);
                    }
                    //break;
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: "Two or more, use a for/array." - Edsger W. Dijkstra.

Comment: `else if(hours == 24)` will never be entered ...

Comment: First thing first, you have `int count_of_sims = 0;` and then `while(count_of_sims < 6)
    {
        count_of_sims = count_of_sims + 1;` which by the way could be refactored to `count_of_sims++` but however, you need 5 simulations, how many loops do you think you will get with this?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a requirement to work in minutes / hours etc?

If not this can be abstracted to a much simpler format.

Instead something like this

```
while(orbitCount < 8) {
    calcPictures(50)
    calcPictures(75)
    calcPictures(25)
    orbitCount++
}
```

This should significantly decrease the number of nested loops you have. The logic will need to be implement for the calcPictures method, where you can pass in the percentage and calculate the number of successful pictures.

Answer (score 0):

1. you have used .50 for 1st, 2nd & 3rd minute. change it for 2nd minute to .75 & for 3rd .25.
2. Use while loop instead of if else ladder for hours
3. Use array of double for orbits.

   ```
   double hour = 3;
   while(hour<=24)
   {
    hour = hour + 3;
    if(minutes == 1)
               {
                   firstOrbit = (int)(Math.random() *100) * .50;
                   System.out.print("Simulation "+hour/3+": Photos of alien: " + firstOrbit);
               }
               //This is the second minute
               else if(minutes == 2)
               {<br>
                   firstOrbit = (int)(Math.random() *100) * .75;
                   System.out.print("Simulation "+hour/3+": Photos of alien: " + firstOrbit);
               }
               //This is the third minute
               else if(minutes == 3)
               {
                   firstOrbit = (int)(Math.random() *100) * .25;
                   System.out.print("Simulation "+hour/3+": Photos of alien: " + firstOrbit);
               }
     minutes=0;
   }
   ```